# Pass file id to Dropzone.js to get file on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm still new to `jQuery` and `Dropzone`.

I want to pass an additional variable to `Dropzone` so I can find and display a specific file on the server. But I'm not sure how to pass the variable to `Dropzone`.

My `Dropzone` code:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    addRemoveLinks :true,
    init: function() {
    thisDropzone = this;
    $.getJSON('<?php echo site_url("disburs/get_file") ?>/',{id : file_id}, function(data) {
            var mockFile = { name: data.name, size: data.size };
            thisDropzone.options.addedfile.call(thisDropzone, mockFile);
            thisDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(thisDropzone, mockFile, "<?php echo base_url()."upload_disbursments/"; ?>"+data.name);
            thisDropzone.emit("complete", mockFile);
        });
    }
};
```

In my code I want to pass `file_id` to `Dropzone` from another function. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could append to formData :

```
init: function() {
     this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData){
            formData.append("id", file_id)
      }),
```

Also, you have a syntax error, it should look like:

```
"<?php echo base_url().'upload_disbursments/'; ?>"+data.name
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I figured out how to get my code to work. I have an `$.ajax();` request that populates a form from the db and I used `$.('#my-dropzone').dropzone(init: function(var file_id = data.receipt; $.getJSON("url",{id : file_id}, function(data) {...} )));` inside the ajax request to get the file details and thumbnail.